# Program wont compile and has a missing return statement error

Tags: java, if-statement, return, public, fibonacci

I can't seem to get my code to compile. Everytime I try, there is an error at the `}`(closing bracket) saying missing return statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner
public class Fibonacci
{
   public static int fibonacciNumber( int n)
   {
       while(n != 00)
       {
           if( n == 0)
           {
               return 0; 
           }
           else if(n == 1)
           {
               return 1;
           }
           else if(n > 1)
           {
               return fibonacciNumber(n-1) + fibonacciNumber(n-2);
           }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a number to calculate(enter 00 to quit): ");
         int n = in.nextInt();

         System.out.println( fibonacciNumber( n));
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the compilation error? You are missing a `;` at the end of your import line.

Comment: You do realise that 00 and 0 are the same integer?

Comment: In my actual code the ';' is there, but when I run the program, the compiler tells me that the final '}' in the fibonacciNumber class has a return error

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up concepts.  fibonacciNumber should either be recursive or it shouldn't be.  The while loop is unnecessary and if a negative number were passed in, your program would never stop!

Comment: you miss  ";" in import java.util.Scanner; and miss return n;type of fibonacciNumber method

Answer (score 2):

Because you're missing a `return` statement.  Consider your method:

```
public static int fibonacciNumber( int n)
{
    while(n != 00)
    {
        // some logic that returns something
    }
}
```

What happens if `n` *does* equal `00`?  Nothing is returned.  The compiler is ensuring that every logical path for a method returns a value.  So after your `while` loop you need to return a value, in case that loop was never entered.

Or, for that matter, what happens if `n` is less than `0`?  None of your current `return` statements would be reached and, in fact, you'd have an infinite loop.

Basically, if your method declares that it returns a value, then it *must* return a value.  Currently you're not guaranteeing that, hence the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

well of course it's asking for a return statement.

```
public static int fibonacciNumber( int n)
```

your function needs to return an integer, but you aren't returning anything because you have a lot of if's with nested returns.

```
  else if(n > 1)
  {
    return fibonacciNumber(n-1) + fibonacciNumber(n-2);
  }
//HERE SHOULD YOUR RETURN BE, outside of the while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you try to develop an application that prints the n-th fibonnaci-Number until the user decides to quit the application. But for that goal, your while-loop is located in the wrong location. It should be located in the main containing the reading of the user input and computation of the fibonnaci-number. Then it becomes clear, that you are missing a `return`, since the fibonacci-method has four possible alternatives:

```
1. n==0
2. n==1
3. n>1
4. all else (which is n<0)
```

You now have the possibility to either return some value for the negative n case, throw an Exception or merge it with the n>1 case.

The latter would be looking something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fibonacci {
    public static int fibonacciNumber( int n) {
        if(n == 0) {
            return 0; 
        } else if(n == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        return fibonacciNumber(n-1) + fibonacciNumber(n-2);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number to calculate(enter 00 to quit): ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        while(n != 0) {
            System.out.println( fibonacciNumber( n));
            in.nextLine(); // Just to parse the line-separator
            n = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

The `in.nextLine()` is required since you type the number into the console but submit it via the enter-key. That results in the Line-Break-Character being read the next time you call `in.nextXXX()` which would result in an Exception. Also, since you use `in.nextInt()` if you type `00` it is parsed to an integer with the value of `0`. Therefore it is not exactly correct to tell the user to type `00` to quit the application.